# Can I run a 120 for a receptacle off a 50 amp circuit?

Tags: receptacle, 240v, junction-box

I have a 50 amp wire capped from a previous oven that was removed. I want to put a receptacle in where this is located.
When I wire it up my tester shows my hot/neutral reversed no matter how I wire it.
The 50 amp has a red, a black and a ground??? No white unless the white was stripped and used for ground.
This is an older house so I'm not sure what I should do

Comment: 50 amp wire probably too big to fit a regular 120 outlet/device.  It is also two hots and a ground.  For 120 you need one hot, one neutral, and a ground.  Might be lucky that there is a white neutral in the cable(is it a cable?).  Don't think you can use a non white/grey wire for neutral.

Comment: @crip659 There's a situation when non-white/grey is allowed for neutral or ground: when the conductor is 4 gauge or heavier. In that case it can be taped or otherwise re-marked for neutral or ground -- but it's not likely Haley's cable is that heavy. :-(

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the junction box in question please?

Comment: Yea its 2 hots and a ground.

Answer (score 1):

This will be a brief answer; I'm sure others could be more complete.

1. No mater what, you have to change to a normal 15 or 20 A breaker for your typical 120 V receptacle or it wont be protected from overcurrent.

2a) You may reuse the existing wiring if it is a multiconductor cable (such as NM). If so, relabel the red wire with white electrical tape on both ends to mark it as neutral. You most likely must also pigtail the exiting wire to a #14 (min for 15 A breaker) or #12 (min for 20 A breaker) with the proper wire nuts to connect to both the receptacle and the breaker (they very likely do not accept the larger gauge existing wire).

2b) If the existing wire is in conduit, the existing red may not be relabeled as white according to 2020 NEC 200.6 (for individual conductors such as THHN, the neutral wire must follow strict color rules). It is easy to pull the old red wire and replace it with the correctly sized white wire of the right type. The other conductors may be reused or replaced.

3. If neither 2a or 2b apply, then replacement is the only option.

Comment: You likely *are* wrong. Re-marking non-white wires to neutral is only an option for 4Ga and larger (50A circuit is likely 8 or 6) where white is generally not manufactured.

Comment: First understand the NEC calls the neutral the "grounded" conductor, this is different from the "grounding" conductor. The 2020 NEC 200.6 Means of identifying Grounded Conductors (E) Multiconductor Cables. Exception No. 1 "Conductors within a multiconductor cable shall be permitted to be re-identified at their terminations..."

Comment: Thank you, NoSparks, that's an important detail that I have added to my answer.

Comment: Understood. Now this circuit also runs my thermostats. I have radiant heat wiring through my ceilings. So I really cant change out from red (hot) to a nuetral right?

Comment: First, conduit would make this easily done correctly, not "can't be done," so that's just plain wrong. In conduit, if you don't have a wire you need, you just pull the wire you need, easy peasy. Second, the wiring described is 99.9% going to be for a 10-50 range plug, with neutral on the grounding wire, and you can't repurpose that or remark a hot as neutral unless it's 4 gauge or larger and it's 99% not going to be 4 gauge or larger.

Comment: @Ecnerwal good point on the conduit case, if conduit is present that certainly makes things easy. I was incorrectly tunnel-visioned on just being able to _reuse_ the exiting cable or wire.

Comment: I updated the answer again based on these comments